# how to integrate to get a heaviside function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to integrate the following functions, either analytically or numerically:

$\int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{\sin^2(\theta)d\theta}{x+y+2\sqrt{xy}\cos(\theta)}$

$\int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)d\theta}{x+y+2\sqrt{xy}\cos(\theta)}$

$\int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\theta)d\theta}{x+y+2\sqrt{xy}\cos(\theta)}$

Any tips or tricks would be appreciated. I believe they should be heaviside functions but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Assuming $x$ and $y$ are fixed parameters, these should all yield to $z=\tan \frac \theta 2$, giving a rational function of $z$ which then you can attack with partial fractions.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%5E2+x%2F(a%2Bb+cos(x))) will do it for you.  This is the first one.

Comment: WA says this here $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\pi  \left(x
   \left(-\sqrt{\frac{2 \sqrt{x y}+x+y}{-2 \sqrt{x
   y}+x+y}}\right)+\left(2 \sqrt{x y}-y\right)
   \sqrt{\frac{2 \sqrt{x y}+x+y}{-2 \sqrt{x
   y}+x+y}}+x+y\right)}{4 x
   y},\Im\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x y}}\right)\neq 0\lor
   \Re\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x y}}\right)\geq 2\lor
   \Re\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x y}}\right)\leq -2\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**: let $x,y>0$ and set $a=\frac{x+y}{2},\quad b=\sqrt{xy}$ hence $a>b>0.$

The first integral can be rewritten as:
$$
{{I}_{1}}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi }{\frac{{{\sin }^{2}}\left( \theta  \right)}{a+b\cos \left( \theta  \right)}d\theta }
$$
And using the [Tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)(as @Ross Millikan commented ) you get:
$$
{{I}_{1}}=\frac{\pi }{2{{b}^{2}}}\left( a-\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}-{{b}^{2}}} \right)
$$
Similarly, for the second and the third integral in question:
$$
\begin{align}
  & {{I}_{2}}=\frac{a\pi }{4{{b}^{4}}}\left( -{{b}^{2}}+2a\left( a-\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}-{{b}^{2}}} \right) \right) \\ 
 & {{I}_{3}}=\frac{\pi }{4{{b}^{3}}}\left( {{b}^{2}}+2a\left( -a+\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}-{{b}^{2}}} \right) \right) \\ 
\end{align}
$$